# How to center 2 Container in Stack one below the other

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code:**

```
Container(
  height: 300,
  width: 300,
  color: Colors.brown,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 50)),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, 0.4),
        child: Container(color: Colors.green, height: 50),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

I want to place the `Green` `Container` right below the `Red`. The above solution works but I have to hardcode the alignment value to `0.4`, I thought of doing it using `Column` but seems like there is no way of doing it. How can I get this done without hardcoding `Alignment`.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: In your case, you could do ` mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,` since that would push the elements to the bottom and since the green element is 1/3 of the height, the red element would be centered.

Comment: This has to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).. Why do you want to do it with a `Column`? You might just want to explain what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot The reason why I don't want to use `Stack` is I will have issues in placing green container right below the red. Can you show an example of doing it without hard coding any value?

Comment: Then my question would be why do you need to be able to do that without hard coding the values? Flutter should scare everything as needed.

Comment: @olevegard I have redesigned the question, please take a look now. Thanks

Comment: Would it help if you use `positioned` instead of `align` and then set the `top` property of the container below to be = to the height of the first container? This way you can store the first container's size in a variable and use that making it SOMEWHAT dynamic i guess? Can't think of anything else.

Comment: @Abbas.M `set the top property of the container below to be = to the height of the first container` -- Thanks but even this won't help, it will simply put the green over the red not below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way and you don't need to hardcode value just change the flex to the size you want and Flutter with calculate the height.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: Container(color: Colors.brown,),),
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.red,),),
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.green,),),
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: Container(color: Colors.brown,),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is how this look:
[image]

Comment: Thank you but this isn't what exactly I am looking for, Red `Container` in your solution isn't at exact center, it is bit above, the center point in this solution is the bottom of red and top of green.

Comment: you can change the flex values to make the size for the proportions you need, like this `Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 5, child: Container(color: Colors.brown,),),
          Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container(color: Colors.red,),),
          Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container(color: Colors.green,),),
          Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container(color: Colors.brown,),),
        ],
      )` this will give the the first container half screen and will separate the extra space in 3 part, you can change those number to whatever you need

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can do it but in this I'll have to test values, if this is looking good, if that is looking good, should I change previous child flex, or this one, and so on. Which is why I decided to use `Stack`, earlier I was using `Column` but it has got some limitations, and made me switch to `Stack`. I appreciate your response Argel, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope it helps:

```
Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.brown,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: SizedBox(height: 1,)),
            Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100),
            Container(color: Colors.green, height: 100),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Sorry I tried this but it doesn't work, set the red and green container height to `50` and see yourself the result. Thanks for answering it though!